# How to properly pass through pointers in parameters

Tags: c++, pointers, matrix

```
int main()
{
    char Grid[8][8] = { '~','~','~','~','~','~','~','~',
               '~','~','~','~','~','~','~','~',
               '~','~','~','~','~','~','~','~',
               '~','~','~','~','~','~','~','~',
               '~','~','~','~','~','~','~','~',
               '~','~','~','~','~','~','~','~',
               '~','~','~','~','~','~','~','~',
               '~','~','~','~','~','~','~','~', };

    int ShipCount = 1;
    while ( ShipCount < 6){
        ShipPlacement(ShipCount, Grid[8][8]);
        ShipCount++;
    }
    ShowGrid(Grid[8][8]);
    return 0;
}

int ShipPlacement(int Shipcount, char Grid[8][8])
{
    srand(time(NULL));

        int VerticalHorizontal = rand() % 2;
        //Randomly generates a number that will decide if the ship is placed horizontally or vertically

        int ShipLocalX = rand() % 5;
        int ShipLocalY = rand() % 5;
        //The X and Y co ords of where the first ship piece will be placed

        //If Horizontal
        if (VerticalHorizontal == 0)
        {
            for (int N = 0; N < Shipcount; N++)
            {
                    Grid[ShipLocalX][ShipLocalY] = 'X';
                    ShipLocalX++;
            }
        }
        //Same code but for vertical placement
        else
        {
            for (int S = 0; S < Shipcount; S++)
            {
                    Grid[ShipLocalX][ShipLocalY] = 'X';
                    ShipLocalY++;
            }
        }
    return **Grid;
}

void ShowGrid(char Grid[8][8])
{
    std::cout << '|';
    for (int y = 0; y < 8; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < 8; x++)
        {
            cout << ' ' << Grid[x][y] << ' ';
            if ((x + 1) % 8 == 0)
            {
                cout << '|' << endl << '|';
            }
        }
    }

    cout << '\r';
}
```

I have tried putting ** before my parameters and putting & before them however they create a lot more issues. My goal is too be able to call these two functions with the parameter of Grid[8][8], but this has created more problems than I thought and pointers to me are still mystical and I have no clue how to solve a problem (I think) that involves them.

Comment: Make `int ShipPlacement(int Shipcount, char Grid[8][8])` into `void ShipPlacement(int Shipcount, char Grid[8][8])` and get rid of the `return **Grid;`

Comment: Then change `ShipPlacement(ShipCount, Grid[8][8]);` to `ShipPlacement(ShipCount, Grid);` and `ShowGrid(Grid[8][8]);` into `ShowGrid(Grid);`

Comment: `srand(time(NULL));` should be moved to the first line of `int main()` you don't want to call this in a loop because time(NULL) has a resolution of 1 second meaning you are likely to get the same seed for multiple iterations of the loop and when you use the same seed you get the same "random" number.

Comment: If possible, use the [`<random>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) header added in C++11. `srand` and `rand` have a few weird quirks and are very unreliable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had one error, and that is every time you tried to pass `Grid` to the functions, you passed the 8th element of the 8th element of `Grid`s. Simply remove the `[8][8]` when passing `Grid` to the functions and tada!

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void ShipPlacement(int, char[8][8]); //declaration
void ShowGrid(char[8][8]); //declaration

int main()
{
    char Grid[8][8] = { '~','~','~','~','~','~','~','~',
               '~','~','~','~','~','~','~','~',
               '~','~','~','~','~','~','~','~',
               '~','~','~','~','~','~','~','~',
               '~','~','~','~','~','~','~','~',
               '~','~','~','~','~','~','~','~',
               '~','~','~','~','~','~','~','~',
               '~','~','~','~','~','~','~','~', };

    int ShipCount = 1;
    while (ShipCount < 6) {
        ShipPlacement(ShipCount, Grid); //only Grid, not Grid[8][8], which is Grid's 8th 8th element
        ShipCount++;
    }
    ShowGrid(Grid); //same here
    return 0;
}

void ShipPlacement(int Shipcount, char Grid[8][8]) //no need for it to return an int, you ignore it anyway
{
    srand(time(NULL));

    int VerticalHorizontal = rand() % 2;
    //Randomly generates a number that will decide if the ship is placed horizontally or vertically

    int ShipLocalX = rand() % 5;
    int ShipLocalY = rand() % 5;
    //The X and Y co ords of where the first ship piece will be placed

    //If Horizontal
    if (VerticalHorizontal == 0)
    {
        for (int N = 0; N < Shipcount; N++)
        {
            Grid[ShipLocalX][ShipLocalY] = 'X';
            ShipLocalX++;
        }
    }
    //Same code but for vertical placement
    else
    {
        for (int S = 0; S < Shipcount; S++)
        {
            Grid[ShipLocalX][ShipLocalY] = 'X';
            ShipLocalY++;
        }
    }
    //return **Grid; No need for a return, you ignore it anyway, and this function is editing Grid anyway, you don't have to assign the result to anything
}

void ShowGrid(char Grid[8][8])
{
    std::cout << '|';
    for (int y = 0; y < 8; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < 8; x++)
        {
            cout << ' ' << Grid[x][y] << ' ';
            if ((x + 1) % 8 == 0)
            {
                cout << '|' << endl << '|';
            }
        }
    }

    cout << '\r';
}
```

You already defined `Grid` as being `[8][8]`, so don't put that every time unless you want to access the 8th element of the 8th row of `Grid` (which is out of range access anyway).